# Where am I being wrong in finding Noble Integer?

Tags: java, integer

**Problem Statement:** Given an integer array, find if an integer p exists in the array such that the number of integers **greater** than p in the array equals to p
If such an integer is found return 1 else return -1.

**My code:**

```
     public int solve(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
        Collections.sort(A);
        for(int i=A.size()-1;i>=0; i--){
            if(A.get(i) == (A.size()-i-1))
                return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

But it is giving wrong output for the some input which I am unable to understand intuitively.i.e, returning 1 when it should return -1. Can anyone point out my mistake(s)?

Comment: what will be happened if the sorted array is not unique ...

Comment: @Mukit09 Will return -1 if all elements are same of the array.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you checked this kind of input out?

Comment: What's the correct result for this array? `[1, 2, 2, 3]`

Comment: Duplicate elements have nothing to do with it AFAIK.  Your code works for me, at least on the inputs I have tested.  I didn't downvote you, but you need to make your problem reproducible.  No one is going to take that dump of 50 numbers and test your code.  Give us a reproducible example of where your code fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all commentators. I didn't observe carefully what could happen when some values are same. The correct solution I have found is as follows.

```
public int solve(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
    Collections.sort(A);
    for(int i=A.size()-1;i>=0; i--){
        if(i<A.size()-1 && A.get(i) == A.get(i+1))continue;
        if(A.get(i) == (A.size()-i-1))
            return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, take note of this solution in Raku, the language you never knew you always wanted.

```
sub noble( @n ) 
{
    # By @HrBollermann (me)
    @n.sort.pairs.grep({ .value + .key == @n.end }).first.value // -1;
}

# Or even shorter,

sub noble( @n ) 
{
    # By @smokemachine
    @n.sort(-*).pairs.grep({ .value == .key }).first.value // -1;
}
```

Comment: If we're golfing: `@n.sort(-*).pairs.grep({ .value == .key }).head.value // -1;` is one char less.  `.first` is really a short-circuited `.grep` and is usually used *with* a matcher.