# Sorted insert position

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

**Problem statement**:Given a sorted array and a target value, return the index if the target is found. If not, return the index where it would be if it were inserted in order.
You may assume no duplicates in the array.

Here are few examples.

```
[1,3,5,6], 5 → 2
[1,3,5,6], 2 → 1
[1,3,5,6], 7 → 4
[1,3,5,6], 0 → 0
```

**My code**:

```
public class Solution {
public int searchInsert(ArrayList<Integer> a, int b) {
    int low = 0, high = a.size()-1;
    int mid = (low+high)/2; 
    int retIndex = mid;
    while(low<=high){
        if(a.get(mid)<b){
            low = mid+1;
            mid = (low+high)/2;
            retIndex = low;
        }
        else{
            high = mid-1;
            mid = (low+high)/2;
            if(high<0) retIndex = 0;
            else retIndex = high;
        }
    }
    return retIndex;
}
}
```

But there is something flaw in this code (returning 1 less or more index on some **large inputs** which is futile to put here) as you can directly check [here](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/sorted-insert-position/#), which I am unable to figure it out. Can anyone point out my mistake? Or what is the correct code for this problem?

**EDIT:** I am presenting the precise input for which it is giving unexpected output.

```
A : [ 3, 4, 18, 19, 20, 27, 28, 31, 36, 42, 44, 71, 72, 75, 82, 86, 88, 97, 100, 103, 105, 107, 110, 116, 118, 119, 121, 122, 140, 141, 142, 155, 157, 166, 176, 184, 190, 199, 201, 210, 212, 220, 225, 234, 235, 236, 238, 244, 259, 265, 266, 280, 283, 285, 293, 299, 309, 312, 317, 335, 341, 352, 354, 360, 365, 368, 370, 379, 386, 391, 400, 405, 410, 414, 416, 428, 433, 437, 438, 445, 453, 457, 458, 472, 476, 480, 485, 489, 491, 493, 501, 502, 505, 510, 511, 520, 526, 535, 557, 574, 593, 595, 604, 605, 612, 629, 632, 633, 634, 642, 647, 653, 654, 656, 658, 686, 689, 690, 691, 709, 716, 717, 737, 738, 746, 759, 765, 775, 778, 783, 786, 787, 791, 797, 801, 806, 815, 820, 822, 823, 832, 839, 841, 847, 859, 873, 877, 880, 886, 904, 909, 911, 917, 919, 937, 946, 948, 951, 961, 971, 979, 980, 986, 993 ]
B : 902
```

The Expected returned value for this input is: 149 
My code returned value for this input is: 148

Comment: We dont like to go to external sites to *check* what your code is doing! Please read [mcve] and update the question accordingly. If you have examples that don't work - include them here!

Comment: @ScaryWombat There might be performance considerations.

Comment: @ScaryWombat `mid` brings down the complexity to `O(log n)`

Comment: @GhostCat I know I shouldn't include link here as no one has time to go through the link for me. But the test case on which it is showing different o/p is very large which might irritate others if I include here.

Comment: What is the reason of downvote?

Comment: Please read [mcve]. We dont ask that you put up **everything**. We ask you to simple provide one, two examples where *expected* and *actual* output do not match up. And the downvotes come in because you are not putting up that [mcve] and instead insist on us checking out whatever off-site.

Comment: @GhostCat I think I can not edit more than this. And also I have provided precise example.

Comment: And that is what we were looking for. As a side note: A) the next step for you would be to learn how to use a debugger. Or simply: add trace prints to your code to **understand** what it is doing. B) in case you want to learn something new, consider turning to a [quickcheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck) based test framework. Because that would allow you to write tests ... that actively *search* the "smallest" example required to make the test fail.

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you. I had provided input in this question which was downvoted saying: "Your question has been downvoted because no one has time to check your code using this large input" . You can check the edit there. I wonder what to do here? Rules are changing from person to person.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45475793/where-am-i-being-wrong-in-finding-noble-integer

Comment: Again again again: read [mcve]. It **clearly** describes what you should do.

Comment: Have you tried debugging already? Compare the debug-steps with how you would do it by hand.

Comment: @MrSmith42 What's more to debug here? It is showing some conceptual problem.And this is minimal code only. Can you give me any question example how to ask?

Comment: If your algorithm does not even work, if you perform it by hand on the example, the algorithm is not sound. So rethink the idea behind your algorithm. If the idea of your algorithm works if you perform it by hand, you can find the flaw  in your implementation by debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will fail for the very basic test case:

**[1,3,5,6], 5 → 2**

you should handle the case when value at mid `a.get(mid) > b` and `a.get(mid)== b`
separately. Also you don't need to separately maintain a variable `retIndex`.

So change your code to:

```
    while(low<=high){
        if(a.get(mid)<b){
            low = mid+1;
            mid = (low+high)/2;                
        }
        else if(a.get(mid) > b){
            high = mid-1;
            mid = (low+high)/2;                
        }
        else return mid;
    }

    return low;//handles the case when no match is found.
```

Comment: That's likely not enough since the example doesn't have an exact match.

Comment: This code is still giving unexpected output on the input mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Rohit. Hope now it would work.

Comment: Thank you. I had this problem only which I was unable to catch. Others too couldn't catch but instead of giving direct answers or mistake philosophizing the issue unnecessary.

Comment: Catch was: "you are looking for the least elements >= x." :-)

Comment: you are searching in the arraylist potentially twice per iteration; value should be stored first in local variable

Comment: @albert_nil The underlying data structure that arraylist uses is array. So random access takes constant time. Hence it wont make any difference.

Comment: but arraylist is not array; it also does some checks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle equality and change the return from the greater branch.

```
while(low<=high){
    if (a.get(mid) == b) return mid;
    else if(a.get(mid)<b){
        low = mid+1;
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        retIndex = low;
    }
    else {
        high = mid-1;
        retIndex = mid;
        mid = (low+high)/2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still giving unexpected results on the input in the question.

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
public class Solution {
public int searchInsert(ArrayList<Integer> a, int b) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.size();
    int candidateIdx = (low + high) / 2;
    int candidateValue;
    int prevCandidateIdx = -1;

    while (low != high ) {
        candidateValue = a.get(candidateIdx);
        if (candidateValue == b) {
            break;
        } else if (candidateValue < b && prevCandidateIdx == candidateIdx -1) {
            candidateIdx++;
            break;
        } else if (candidateValue < b) {
            low = candidateIdx;
        } else if (prevCandidateIdx == candidateIdx + 1) {
            break;
        } else {
            high = candidateIdx;
        }
        prevCandidateIdx = candidateIdx;
        candidateIdx = (low + high)/2;
    }
    return candidateIdx;
}
}
```